# Sorting array of events based on dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, sorting

I am importing events from a Google Calendar and parsing them for display elsewhere. I'm stuck on events that span a range of dates. For instance:

> Event 1
>   Date: 4/29/2013 - 5/03/2013
>
> Event 2
>   Date: 5/01/2013 - 5/03/2013
>
> Event 3
>   Date: 5/03/2013 - 5/06/2013

When I display the events for 5/03/2013 I need to have Event 1, 2 and 3 show up.
My plan so far has been to generate a DatePeriod containing all of the dates between the beginning and end date of the event then iterate through it adding the event information under the key of the date. In other words, I'll have an array of dates that each contain an array of events.
This is what I have so far. I think I'm along the right path but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public function groupEvents()
            {
                foreach($this->events as $event)
                {
                    // Date is in the format of "Mon Apr 29, 2013 to Wed May 1, 2013".
                    if(preg_match_all("/\w{3} \w{3} \d{0,2}. \d{4}/", $event->getDate(), $matches))
                    {
                        // If there is more than one match then the event spans multiple days.
                        if(count($matches[0] > 1))
                        {
                            // Following line grabs the first date in the format of "Apr 29 2013"
                            $bDate = substr($matches[0][0],4,6) . substr($matches[0][0],11);
                            // Following line grabs the last date in the format of "May 1,2013"
                            $eDate = substr($matches[0][1],4,6) . substr($matches[0][1],11);
                            // Create a new DateTime based on the beginning date
                            $begin = new DateTime($bDate);
                            // Create a new DateTime based on the ending date
                            $end = new DateTime($eDate);
                            // Interval of 1 day.
                            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
                            // Create a DatePeriod of all dates between the beginning and end dates
                            $period = new DatePeriod($begin,$interval,$end);


                            foreach($period as $d)
                            {
                                // Problems start...
                                $this->newList[$d] = array($d => $newEvent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can't you use the `timeMax` and `timeMin` parameters to the Event List  method to select events on a particular date?

Comment: Each event should have a start_date and end_date (may be the same for 1 day), then do a search with `WHERE mydate BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`. Simples

Comment: also you can use `$twodates=explode(' to ', $date_string);` to split the dates up. And then `$datestart=strtotime($twodates[0]);` to create a timestamp that `date("Y-m-d", $datestart)` can use.

Comment: I know what the start and end are. I use them to set up the DatePeriod. I'm just having trouble setting up an array of all events that's based on the date. The first dimension of the array will contain days while the second dimension contains events under those dates.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the events and echo matching events (you need to create the array).

```
function groupEvents($mydate='2013-03-05')
{
    foreach($this->events as $event)
    {
        // Date is in the format of "Mon Apr 29, 2013 to Wed May 1, 2013".
        $event_date=$event->getDate();
        // check if TO exists in the event date
        if(stristr($event_date, ' to '))
        {
            $twodates=explode(" to ", $event_date);
            $start_date=strtotime($twodates[0]);
            $end_date=strtotime($twodates[1]);

            if( (date("Y-m-d", $start_date)<=$mydate) && ($mydate<=date("Y-m-d", $end_date)) )
            {
                // assuming $event->getName() will get the name of the event
                echo 'Event '.$event->getName().' '.date("m/d/Y", $start_date).' to '.date("m/d/Y", $start_date);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $start_date=strtotime($event_date);

            if(date("Y-m-d", $start_date)==$mydate)
            {
                // assuming $event->getName() will get the name of the event
                echo 'Event '.$event->getName().' '.date("m/d/Y", $start_date);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach it would be to first parse the Calendar text into an array. To make things easier I'd declare an `Event` class to organise each event and store pertinent information. I'd declare a method within the `Event` class called something like `is_active`, which takes an `DateTime` argument as its only parameter and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the date falls within the event's start/end dates. From there it's pretty easy to filter your existing array of all events into subsets for a particular date if you need it.

Something like the following should get you started:

```
class Event {
    // instance variables.
    private $_name;
    private $_begin;
    private $_end;

    // retrieve the name of the current Event instance.
    public function name() { return $this->_name; }

    // build a new immutable Event instance
    public function __construct($name, $begin, $end) {
        $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_begin = $begin;
        $this->_end = $end;
    }

    // check whether the $date argument falls between this Event's start/end dates.
    // $date is assumed to be a valid DateTime object
    public function is_active($date) {
        return $date >= $this->_begin && $date <= $this->_end;
    }
}
```

Now, to continue in a more `OOP` design, we'll also create a class to manage a set of events, I'll use `Calendar` in this case. I've added a static method to parse a calendar from a file as well.

```
class Calendar {
    // Regular Expression for parsing the date range of an event. Update this if the format changes.
    // currently it assumes strings like: "Date: mm/dd/YYYY - mm/dd/YYYY"
    const PREG_DATE = '~^Date:\\s*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,4})\\s*-\\s*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})~i';
    // for date_create_from_format, matches the above Regular Expressions assumptions about date ordering
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y';

    // hold onto all the events
    private $_events;

    public function __construct($evts) {
        $this->_events = $evts;
    }

    // Retrieve all events active on a certain date.
    // $date is assumed to be a valid DateTime object
    public function get_events($date) {
        // If using PHP less than 5.3, you'll need to rewrite this without using closures.
        // basically just filters the array according to the results of calling "is_active" on each
        // of the event objects.
        return array_filter($this->_events, function($obj) use($date) {
            return $obj->is_active($date);
        });
    }

    // Very simple parsing function to read a Calendar from file
    // fairly rigid formatting expected.
    //
    // Event Name
    // Date: formatted date <-- must be on the very next line
    // <any number of blank lines can follow the above name/dates pair>
    // ...
    public static function from_file($filepath) {
        $events = null;
        $fs = fopen($filepath, 'r');

        if ($fs !== false) {
            $events = array();
            while (($buffer = fgets($fs)) !== false) {
                $buffer = trim($buffer);
                if ($buffer !== "") { // skip empty lines
                    if (($dateString = fgets($fs)) === false || preg_match(self::PREG_DATE, $dateString, $matches) !== 1) { 
                        break; // Invalid format reached (either premature EOF or unrecognized date format
                    } 

                    // Create a new Event object and add it to the array with the parsed values.
                    $events[] = new Event(
                        $buffer, 
                        date_create_from_format(self::DATE_FORMAT, $matches[1]),
                        date_create_from_format(self::DATE_FORMAT, $matches[2])
                    );
                }
            }
            fclose($fs);
        }

        return $events !== null ? new Calendar($events) : null;
    }
}
```

Easy as that. A Calendar controls a set of `Event` objects. By calling `get_events` you can retrieve an array of all events active on a particular day. For example:

```
$calendar = Calendar::from_file('foo.txt');
var_dump($calendar->get_events(date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '5/03/2013')));
```